# Integrating GeoExplorer in a web application

Tags: geoexplorer, opengeo-suite-composer

I am working in geoportal. 
I would ask if integrating GeoExplorer in my application  will facilitate the task of visualizing a group of layers existing in my project.
If Yes, How can I integrate it in my application.

Comment: Can you elaborate more in your question how you want GeoExplorer to work with a rubric of layers?  Your question is currently very vague.

Comment: My pupose is to integrate GeoExplorer in my web application in order to visualize a group of layers existing in my project.

Comment: Please [edit](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/277121/edit) your question to add more details, please don't use the comments